# Small app and limited functions, shall I go with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, web-frameworks

I have an app that will do calculations from one input, dividing it out to many outputs along with its data visualization. The calculations is very complicated; many variables, many statements, and hard to connect it with d3js. I believe frameworks are meant to make things easier and faster, though I have accomplished that using HTML/Javascript, with very much codes.

Also I consider applying the app into mobile systems.

So will AngularJS be much better for such projects?